# Estimating a surprise of a word in context

Tags: natural-language, entropy, information-theory, information-retrieval

What will be the best way to estimate the entropy/surprise of a word in a specific context?
Let's say to compare the surprise of:
context:

> "I watched the movie in my"

word:

> Computer

I thought about:

> entropy(word | context) = entropy(I watched the movie in my computer)
>   - entropy( I watched the movie in my)

What do you think? is this a good method? Are there better ones?

Comment: What I immediately thought of is wrongly spelled words are also very surprising

Comment: @MinhTriet You are correct but I use a validated corpus so there are no mis-spelling

Comment: Karpathy used RNN to predict next word in a sentence [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/). He calculates the next word given the previous words, should give you some hints

Comment: @MinhTriet would you say RNN in better for this task then "regular" n-gram model?

Comment: Size of n-gram models heavily depends on how large your corpus is, and RNN does not have that limitation. I am under an impression that RNN can be faster than n-grams, because you do not have to search through a huge probability dictionary

Comment: @MinhTriet and which one should be more accurate?